# How to plot this geometric object in 3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, linear-algebra, parallelization

Let $v_{0}=(1,0,0)$. Then how to plot in 3D the geometric object $$\left\{ \left(v_{0}\cdot v_{1},v_{0}\cdot v_{2},v_{1}\cdot v_{2}\right):v_{1},v_{2}\in\mathbb{R}^{3} \text{are unit vectors}\right\}  $$  in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$  in Mathemtica? Thanks.

Comment: As written, the set seems to consist of a single point. You should maybe check your expression once more.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher $v_1$ and $v_2$ vary, so it should not be a single point. Best regards.

Comment: Well, the _only_ point $(x,y,z)$ that is contained in the set you wrote is $(v_0 \cdot v_1, v_0 \cdot v_2, v_1 \cdot v_2)$. Thanks for listening.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Again, $v_0$ is a constant vector, but both $v_1$ and $v_2$ vary, so the should not be a single point. Best regards.

Comment: For example, do you get the same point in the set when $v_2=(1,0,0), v_3=(1,0,0)$ and when $v_2=(0,-1,0), v_3=(0,0,-1)$ ? Best regards.

Comment: Please, _read the set definition that you have posted here_. If the vectors $v_i$ change, the point $(x,y,z)$ changes, but the set still consists of a single point.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  You know what it really means, so do you have a better way to express it?

Comment: No, I do not know what it really means because you have not told me, yet. I am not kidding here. We are discussing here about a matter that is like me saying: "Uh, there is only half a bottle of milk in the fridge; so maybe you should consider to buy a new one." and you are like "Thanks, but no. The weather could change." That just does not make sense. I won't continue to discuss this with you. I am off here.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: It is a completely different thing now.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  Then could you plot it in Mathematica? Thanks.

Comment: Not really satisfactory: convex hull of 10000 randomly chosen points from the set `ConvexHullMesh[With[{v0={1,0,0}},Map[{v0.#[[1]],v0.#[[2]],#[[1]].#[[2]]}&,RandomPoint[Sphere[],{10000,2}]]]]`

Comment: More accurate version is `ContourPlot3D[c^2+x1^2-2 c x1 x2+x2^2==1,{x1,-1,1},{x2,-1,1},{c,-1,1}]` but it requires some math preprocessing

Answer (score 5):

Could define it parametrically.

```
pr = ParametricRegion[{{x1, y1, x1*y1 + x2*y2 + x3*y3}, 
    x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 == 1 && y1^2 + y2^2 + y3^2 == 1},
{x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3}];
```

We can "see" it using `Region`.

```
Region[pr]
```

[image]